# jQuery function to replace bloated code

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to hide/show divs.First of all I hide them all and then I show the one relevant one.

```
$('.cart').children().hide();                                                           

$('.product1').click(function() {
    $('.cart').children().hide();               
    $('.pro1').show();
});

$('.product2').click(function() {
    $('.cart').children().hide();               
    $('.pro2').show();
});

$('.product3').click(function() {
    $('.cart').children().hide();  
    $('.pro3').show();
});
```

Is there a way that I can just create one function that takes an input of which a class is being clicked and shows the relevant div?

product1 will control pro1
product2 will control pro2

and so on - the numbers at the end will always be consistent.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: there's probably a better way to do this rearranging the classes and id's of the divs. However, it's hard for me to figure it out without the markup code.

Answer (score 3):

If you mark all relevant elements with some attribute (say 'data-id'):

```
<a class="product" data-id="1">...</a>
<a class="product" data-id="2">...</a>
<a class="product" data-id="3">...</a>
...
<div class="cart">
   <div class="pro" data-id="1">...</div>
   <div class="pro" data-id="2">...</div>
   <div class="pro" data-id="3">...</div>
</div>
```

Then this should work:

```
$('.product').click (function() {
   $('.cart').children().hide();
   $('.pro[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: This is also a great way to do it. :) Using `data-something` means you can have limitless attributes, rather than using the `rel` attr.

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-id')` should be replaced by `$(this).data('id')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var children = $('.cart').children(); 
children.hide().click(function() {
    /* assuming classes are in the form of product1... product<n> */
    var index = $(this).attr('class').replace(/^product/, '');

    children.hide();               
    $('.pro' + index).show();
});
```

Comment: This does rather assume that `productN` is the only class on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class to each of your three HTML elements `.product1`, `.product2` and `.product3`, for example `common-class`, and try:

```
$('.common-class').click(function() {
    $('.cart').children().hide();               
    $(this).show();
});
```

**EDIT:** Or even better, whithout thoose added class, that should work too:

```
$('.cart').children().each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.cart').children().hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

**RE-EDIT:** Misunderstood, see F. Calderan answer.

Comment: this is exactly what i meant in my comment. +1

Comment: Would this not show the summary div (product#) rather than the detail one (pro#)?

Comment: Yes, for me is F. Calderan answer the best.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If you know that the elements in question will **only** have one class on them (`product1`, etc.), then:

```
$('.cart').children().hide();                                                           
$('.product1, .product2, .product3').click(function() {
    var num = this.className.substring(7);
    $('.cart').children().hide();               
    $('.pro' + num).show();
}
```

If they may have other classes as well (the more likely case):

```
$('.cart').children().hide();                                                           
$('.product1, .product2, .product3').click(function() {
    var classes = this.className.split(' ');
    $.each(this.className.split(' '), function(index, cls) {
        var num;
        if (cls.substring(0, 7) === "product") {
            num = cls.substring(7);
            $('.cart').children().hide();               
            $('.pro' + num).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd probably consider refactoring a bit. Perhaps a `product` class and a `data-num` attribute giving the product number:

```
<div class="product" data-num="1">Product 1</div>
```

...which makes it easier:

```
$('.cart').children().hide();                                                           
$('.product').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('data-num');
    $('.cart').children().hide();               
    $('.pro' + num).show();
}
```

Attributes starting with the [`data-*` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) are valid on any element.

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-num')` should be replaced by `$(this).data('num')`

Comment: @sp00m: No, it shouldn't. It *can be*, but that doesn't mean it *should*. Personally, I'm not a fan of the whole way jQuery's `data` function conflates and confuses things. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it this way. All the `productx` are of class `product` and therefore should all have the class `product` and the product id/number should be referenced another way.

I would use the `rel` attribute:

```
<div class="product" rel="1">Product 1</div>
<div class="product" rel="2">Product 2</div>
<div class="product" rel="3">Product 3</div>
```

Now you can do:

```
$('.product').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('.cart').children().hide();
  $('.pro'+rel).show();
  // this is for show however
  // as above I probably wouldn't
  // use the class to reference
  // these elements. Classes can
  // be applied to many elements.
  // I would use id rather than
  // class. e.g. <div id="pro1">
});
```

Comment: @Thilo will that really make it more flexible? Having the product id in the `rel` attr will be the most flexible. If OP wants to introduce AJAX queries or something similar in the future having it as the product id is probably the best way.

Comment: Depends on if he wants to use the event handler for things other than products or not. And to throw in a third option, use a DOM id and do `rel="#pro1"`.

Comment: AFAIK, `rel=""` isn't valid when not used within a `<a />`. I would better use the custom attribute `data-toShow=".rel#"` and access it with `$(this).data("toShow")` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/))

Comment: Yes. :) Using data-whatever is much better. And is also more descriptive (for maintenence)